# Vercel deployment failing for some projects, but not all when using mono repo

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vercel

I have a strange problem that I'm struggling to solve as it's quite intermittent. I have a single repo on Vercel that is powering 47 projects.

The project itself is a Vue frontend app using Vite.

Ignored Build Step is set to "Only build production". I am on the Pro plan, setup with 4 concurrent builds.

I did a deployment earlier today and all projects were successfully deployed. I then tried doing another deployment that contained a small CSS fix and it only seems to be deploying 12 of the projects now.

I keep getting the following on Git: **"Some checks were not successful - 36 failing and 12 successful checks"**

Clicking on "Details" for the failed deployments doesn't redirect me anywhere.

In vercel, there's no logs or records of these failed deployments.

Would really appreciate some help on this...

[image]

Comment: Contact vercel support?

Comment: I have done but thought I'd ask on Stackoverflow to see whether anyone else has encountered the same issue. I thought maybe I'm missing something obvious and I ideally need a fix asap.